# match_template from skimage returns 1X1 area

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I'm trying to coalign sequential images of astonomical object using match_template from skiimage. Images are numpy areas 500x500, and very similar. The only difference is introduced by slow rotation of the object itself (movement is less than pixel between images, I tried to increase difference by making average template over 10 images, but it did not help much, result is almost the same). As the result I'm getting only 1x1 array

```
   In [22]: result
   Out[22]: array([[ 0.98132336]], dtype=float32)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took me some time, but I figured out what is going on. 
The problem is that images are too similar to each other. If the change between images is a sub-pixel resolution, this particular code will return just one number, simply because images do match to each other almost perfectly.
The workaround I found was based on my old code written in IDL, where, by using the Fourier transform I managed to calculate the amount of shift I need to use between images in series so that I can co-align them. 
I needed very good precision because of the analysis I need to do on the images.  
If you bump into the same problem, send me a message. I will gladly share the code. You're free to use it, as long as you cite me in your paper. 
When I publish the paper, I will put all codes I used for analysis (including this one) on GitHub. Same condition will apply.